# How do you apply the MapBox Pencil Theme to a localhost map?

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I am looking at [this Pencil theme](https://www.mapbox.com/gallery/#pencil) for MapBox.

[image]

I have a very basic map, just getting started, I am new to MapBox.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src='https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.1.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <div id='map' style='width: 400px; height: 300px;'></div>
    <script>
      mapboxgl.accessToken = 'my-token'
      var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11'
      })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

How do I convert it to pencil theme? Does [this](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-studio-pencil.tm2) help? How do I apply that locally? Their [blog](https://blog.mapbox.com/designing-the-pencil-map-style-f8c57dae0e88) doesn't really offer much help.

I can go to mapbox studio and see a pencil map, and click "share" then "Download pencil.zip", but what do I do with that style.json?